# Cast to bool: `!!` vs `(bool)`

Tags: c, casting, boolean

Is there any difference in using `!!x` vs `(bool)x`?

Assuming `__STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L` and `#include <stdbool.h>`

Do both of them guarantee that the result is either `0` or `1`, and that no overflow occurs, no matter the size and value of `x`?

Comment: `(bool)x` is the true state of bool (if x is nonzero), but that's not exactly the same as `1`

Comment: bool has two states, you can call them whatever you want but I hoped it was clear which one I meant by "the true state". The standard doesn't give the states official names

Comment: The expressions `while(x) /*...*/;`, `while(!!x) /*...*/;`, and `while((_Bool)x) /*...*/;` are equivalent. I prefer the 1st. Same for `if` and the *condition* part of the `for`.

Comment: It is more for when you actually need the number `1` for some reason.

Comment: @M.M Ok, I re-read your comment and now I understood it. My fault.  However, the standard does guarantee that `true == 1`.  The thing I am not sure about is if `(bool)2 == 1`

Comment: `(bool)2 == 1` is true, because the integer promotions take `(bool)2` to `(int)1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`!!x` (in C, not C++) has type `int`. `(bool)x` (with `<stdbool.h>` included) has type `_Bool`.
While `_Bool`s are quick to be promoted to `int`s, the two can be told apart from inside a `_Generic`.

`!!x` (or the equivalent `0!=x`) will always be either `0` or `1` and `(bool)x` will always be either `(bool)0` or `(bool)1` and if it compiles (=doesn't violate any constraints) and `x` is defined, it will always be well defined.

Overflow in expressions like `!!x+INT_MAX` or `(bool)x+INT_MAX` (`bool` promoted to `int`) is still a concern.

---

References:

[6.3.1.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.2): (_Bool)x <=> (_Bool)(0!=x)

> 1 When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the
>   value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1.59)

(
[6.2.5p18](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p18), [6.2.5p21](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p21) -- scalars are numeric types or pointers

> Integer and floating types are collectively called arithmetic types.
>   ...
>
> Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called scalar
>   types. ...
>   )

[6.5.3.3p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.3p5): !!x <=> 0!=x

> The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of its
>   operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares
>   equal to 0. The result has type int. The expression !E is equivalent
>   to (0==E).

Comment: Please, answer also to the second part of the question, which is also the most important for most use cases.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito OK